# Hiding a table row for a cell containing a span

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide a row which contains in one of the cells a specific span element.  The following code is what I have so far - but there is no getElementsByTagName for a tr

What else can I do to get the row?  Thanks !

```
<table id='tableContainer'>
<tr><td><span id='xyz'>Hide</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id='abc'>Show</span></td></tr>
</table>

container = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
items = container.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    spans = items.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
        if (spans.id == 'xyz') {
            items.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName works for tr elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spans` and `items` are arrays of nodes, so you forgot to get each one by array index, it should be like this,

```
<table id='tableContainer'>
<tr><td><span id='xyz'>Hide</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id='abc'>Show</span></td></tr>
</table>

container = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
items = container.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    spans = items[j].getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
        if (spans[i].id == 'xyz') {
            items[j].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/vaMMY/)

**UPDATE:**

And don't forget to put `style` before `display`.

```
items[j].display = 'none'; // false
items[j].style.display = 'none'; // true
```

Answer (score 1):

So let us debug a little:

```
container = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
console.log(container)  //<-- Gives you tag element
items = container.getElementsByTagName('tr');
console.log(items); //<-- Gives you HTML Collection

for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    spans = items.getElementsByTagName('span');  //<-- error says items.getElementsByTagName is not a function
    for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
        if (spans.id == 'xyz') {  //<--error here [not referencing index]
            items.display = 'none';  //<--error here [not setting style and index]
        }
    }
}
```

Problem here is you are not indexing each tr, you are trying to run it on the whole html collection.

```
spans = items.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

should be

```
spans = items[j].getElementsByTagName('span');
```

You need to do the same thing in the spans loop so the final code would be

```
container = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
console.log(container)  //<-- Gives you tag element
items = container.getElementsByTagName('tr');
console.log(items); //<-- Gives you HTML Collection

for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    spans = items[j].getElementsByTagName('span');  //<-- use index
    items.getElementsByTagName is not a function
    for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
        console.log(spans[i].id)
        if (spans[i].id == 'xyz') {  //<-- use index
            items[j].style.display = 'none';  //<-- use index and display
        }
    }
}
```

Running example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WXNG5/)

Comment: But iterating through the spans does not give me the table row the span belongs to

Comment: Because you have tons of errors, look at my updated post. You really need to learn how to debug. The JavaScript debugger is your friend!

Comment: thanks ocanal beat you to the punch with a full example but you got it too